# Jsf form for many to many relationship

Tags: hibernate, jsf

I have these 2 entity with many to many relationship.

```
@Entity
public class Stammdaten {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Language> languages = new ArrayList<Language>();
}

@Entity
public class Language {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "languages")
    private List<Stammdaten> stammdatens = new ArrayList<Stammdaten>();
}
```

I have a list of 20 languages already saved in Language table. Now when a user fill up stammdaten form, user select one of the 20 languages from a  drop down list. Then when the form is submitted, the join table for stammdaten and language should be updated. How can I do that?

Currently I have this form

```
<h:form id="stammdaten">

        <h:message for="RegisterGroupPanel" style="color:red;" />

        <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="RegisterGroupPanel">

            <h:outputLabel for="firstName" value="First name : " />
            <h:inputText id="firstName" value="#{stammdatenController.stammdaten.firstName}" /> <br />

        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{what should be here??}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{languageController.list()}" var="language" itemValue="#{language.id}" itemLabel="#{language.name}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>


        <h:commandButton action="#{stammdatenController.create()}" value="Send" />
```

I don't understand what should be the value here in the above code `what should be here???`

Edit: Controller

```
@ManagedProperty("#{languageService}")
LanguageService languageService;

private Language language = new Language();
private List<Language> languages;


public void create(){
        stammdatenService.save(stammdaten);
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ApplicationHelpers.setSuccessMessage("Application created successfully successfully", null);
    }
```

Comment: But what do you have in stammdatenController.create() ? Regarding "what should be here??" you just set it to a property of a managed bean? Can you show us your backing bean and the controller?

Comment: Please see the update. I dont know what to do here "what should be here??". because I don't know how to insert a row in join table through form

Comment: I think your question is related to JPA, not JSF.. what should be here?? should be stammdatenController. languageService I guess. But what is stammdaten in the save method?

Answer (score 0):

Your selectonemenu uses `language.id` as itemvalue. 
Let's assume this is `int` in your DB. So you need `private selectedLanguageId` (and create getter and setter), then use `#{selectedLanguageId}` instead of your `#{what should be here}`.

Then in your create action you should do your logic manually - get the language based on selected id and send it to your service.